# Wpf : Over-ridding Mouse Cursor when outside application element dragged

Tags: wpf, data-binding, drag-and-drop, mouse, mouse-cursor

I am trying to overide the mouse cursor when element from outside application is dragged on toolbar in application.I tried using :
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;

But this seems to be working for elements inside the the applications only. How we can over-ride the Mouse cursor when outside element is dragged into application ?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that in the PreviewDragOver event handler of the same ui element that is processing the drop event. Like so:

```
<Grid AllowDrop="True"
      Drop="Grid_Drop" 
      PreviewDragOver="Grid_PreviewDragOver">
    <WhatEver />
</Grid>
```

To keep my code behind clean, I forward the events to the appropriate ViewModel:

```
private void Grid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (DataContext is MyFancyViewModel myVm)
    {
        myVm.Grid_Drop(sender, e);
    }
}
private void Grid_PreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (DataContext is MyFancyViewModel myVm)
    {
        myVm.Grid_PreviewDragOver(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Finally, the ViewModel knows how to handle data.

```
public void Grid_PreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs args)
{
    var data = args.Data.GetData(typeof(MyDragDropDataType)) as MyDragDropDataType;

    if (data is null) // incompatible data
    {
        args.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
        args.Handled = true;
    }
}

public void Grid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs args)
{
    var data = args.Data.GetData(typeof(MyDragDropDataType)) as MyDragDropDataType;

    Trace.WriteLine($"{nameof(Grid_Drop)}, data = {data}");

    if (data is null) // avoid incompatible data
    {
        return;
    }
    // process incoming data
}
```